# Cumulative percentage on column without group by

Tags: python, cumsum

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['2020-08', 'Peter', 0.5], ['2020-08', 'Tom', 0.29], ['2020-08', 'Kurt', 0], ['2020-09', 'Peter', 0], ['2020-09', 'Tim', 0.79], ['2020-09', 'Kurt', 0]]  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Name', 'Breakage']) 
df1
```

[image]

I would like to have a new column with cumulative percentages based on columns "Date" and Breakage. The required dataframe should looks as:

[image]

If i understand it correctly, the dataframe is already grouped_by.
The goal is to have a Cumsum Percentage of the "Date" column based on "Breakage".

All the solutions i have found are groupby based, which does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the job

```
dfs = []
for _, date_df in df1.groupby('Date', as_index=False):
    date_df['CumSumPercetage'] = date_df['Breakage'] / date_df['Breakage'].sum()
    dfs.append(date_df)
df2 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Although it based on groupby I don't see the problem.

Comment: Wow! You saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: @Parsyk - Just a reminder to accept and upvote answers which you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df1['CumsumPercentage'] = df1['Breakage'] / df1.groupby('Date')['Breakage'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
     Date   Name  Breakage  CumsumPercentage
0  2020-08  Peter      0.50          0.632911
1  2020-08    Tom      0.29          0.367089
2  2020-08   Kurt      0.00          0.000000
3  2020-09  Peter      0.00          0.000000
4  2020-09    Tim      0.79          1.000000
5  2020-09   Kurt      0.00          0.000000
```